# pointer swap weirdness

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following working code, for red-black tree rotations.

```
 void BalancedTree::rotateLeft(Node* & x){
 37   Node* y = x->right;
 38 
 39   x->right = y->left;//slice y's left child
 40   x->right->parent = x;
 41 
 42   y->left = x;//switch x and y's parentship
 43   Node* xp = x->parent;//for some reason, y->parent = x->parent causes logic
     errors.
 44   x->parent = y;
 45   y->parent = xp;
 46   
 47   if (y->parent == nil) root = y;//fix grandparent
 48   else if (y->parent->parent->left == x) y->parent->parent->left = y;
 49   else y->parent->parent->right = y;
 50 }
```

When the line 43 and 45 was replace by (keep 44)

```
y->parent = x->parent
```

Or, just exchange line 44 and 45, the content of Node pointer by x was changed. All I wanted to do was this: change the pointer (parent) in Node (pointed by y), and let it point to x's parent.

The Node structure is:

```
struct Node{
  Node* parent;
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
  int value;
};
```

Am I missing something? Basic properties of pointers?

EDIT: page 313 Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms

```
LEFT-ROTATE(T, x)
1 y = x.right
2 x.right = y.left
3 if y.left != T.nil
4   y.left.p = x
5 y.p = x.p
6 if x.p == T.nil
7   T.root = y
8 elseif x == x.p.left
9    x.p.left = y
10 else x.p.right = y
11 y.left = x
12 x.p = y
```

EDIT2: Here is the code NOT working:

```
 36 void BalancedTree::rotateLeft(Node* & x){
 37   Node* y = x->right;
 38 
 39   x->right = y->left;//slice y's left child
 40   x->right->parent = x;
 41 
 42   y->left = x;//switch x and y's parentship
 43   y->parent = x->parent;
 44   x->parent = y;
 45   
 46   
 47   if (y->parent == nil) root = y;//fix grandparent
 48   else if (y->parent->parent->left == x) y->parent->parent->left = y;
 49   else y->parent->parent->right = y;
 50 }
```

Comment: Rather than describing the changes you made, show the exact code that you tried to use to remove `xp`.

Comment: I don't understand the edit. Your code is completely unrelated to it. It doesn't match at all. Why don't you carefully implement Cormen's algo?

Answer (score 0):

The two versions of your code that you present are indeed equivalent. However, your implementation of this algorithm bears little relation to the algorithm as written in your Cormen reference. Your code should read:

```
void BalancedTree::rotateLeft(Node* & x){
    Node* y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;
    if (y->left != nil)
        y->left->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;
    if (x->parent == nil)
        root = y;
    else if (x == x->parent->left)
        x->parent->left = y;
    else
        x->parent->right = y;
    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;
}
```